# swift2 how to log when app is in background?

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

I'm developing an app which performs some processes in the background (CLLocation for beacon detection and opening URLSession in background), but one of these functions is not working properly in the background (when app is not active) despite working fine when app is in the foreground.

I would like to know how to debug my app when it is not active as there are no logs in Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your logs to a file (for example see https://github.com/melke/SlimLogger) or to a service (i.e. Loggly, etc.).

Comment: I'm finally using SlimLogger which is quite a nice tool !

Comment: How can you log to a file using SlimLogger as suggested on your answer?

Comment: @HugoAllexisCardona You'll need to create a LogDestination that writes how you want to in `log()`. I don't think I have a public repo with one of these handy, but the code isn't too complicated (well…my code is complicated, but that's because I have an elaborate background uploading system, but it doesn't have to be complicated.)

Comment: @RobNapier Thank you for the response. I actually tried with the LogDestination implementation but found it too complicated, first it was hard to write on a file, I was getting an error and second I thought it would be hard as well to read the log file later, I can't just go on a file explorer app and visualize the file. So I ended up just using the Firebase DebugView to log backgrounded app events and its way easier. I started iOS development 1 week ago, I usually do Android which if you ask me is way better, faster and easier to develop than iOS... XCode kinda sucks haha. Just my opinion.

Comment: If you're only a week into iOS, I wouldn't bother too much with logging systems like this. Stick to the basics, which for Swift is just "print" and when you want to get fancy, use os_log. They're not sufficient for production work IMO, but don't get sidetracked on those kinds of problems. Xcode console logging and (very) occasionally pulling logs from the Xcode Devices window will get you a long way. If Firebase is working for you, that's fine too. My experience in Android is that may things are simpler, and many things are harder. It's just different. Best of luck.

Comment: To clarify for future readers, SlimLogger does not write to a file. This is something we have to do ourselves.